# Delete automation records in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search. I want to store data in a date range. I want to remove old data.

I use api for deleting data in date range which i want to remove.

I see time to live api in ES but it is deprecated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use time-based idex name patterns such as `myindex-YYYY-MM-DD` and drop old indexes on demand

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html

To delete old indices you should use [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) and its [index deletion feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html).

Comment: Thanks you. I used time-based index name patterns. is there a way to automate?